# Make ping continue running even if network disappears

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, ping

I am evaluating an ISP quality by means of a ping test using the following command in terminal (ubuntu 18.04):

```
sudo ping -i .001 -w 900 -W 899 www.google.com  |
while read pong; do
    echo "$(date +"%T.%N"): $pong"
done > "test_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d__%H%M").txt"
```

The test is intended to run for 15 minutes (-w 900), however if internet connection is lost (i.e. router is turned off), the command stops running and the text file is closed.

I tried to use `-W` option (timeout) without success.

Is there a way to make the command to try to reconnect and proceed with the test?

It is important for the analysis to track those disconnections.

Comment: I don't think you need `sudo` there.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137133

Comment: I need sudo because -i .001 is too low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following https://serverfault.com/questions/503820/linux-ping-command-exits-early-due-to-icmp-host-unreachable

This is an acceptable solution:

```
sudo timeout 900s ping -i .001 www.google.com  |
while read pong; do 
   echo "$(date +"%T.%N"): $pong"
done > "test_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d__%H%M").txt"
```

As stated in the link, there is an strange behavior of `-w` option which exits ping command after network disconnection.

The drawback of this solution is that the ping statistics output is lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the check with a loop that will run for 15 minutes. Each test can be limited to 1 minute,

```
START=$SECONDS
while ((SECONDS-START<15*60)) ; do
    S1=$SECONDS
    sudo ping -i .001 -w 60 -W 899 www.google.com  |
    while read pong; do
        echo "$(date +"%T.%N"): $pong"
    done
    if ((SECONDS-S1<59)) ; then
        echo "Disconnect"
        sleep 1
    fi

done > "test_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d__%H%M").txt"
```

Comment: Even simpler, you can reset the value of `SECONDS` to 0 before the loop, then simply check if `SECONDS` is still less than `15*60`.